# Python Pandas Filter names of Columns What have one or more NaN

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

Hello can you help me please ?
I have CSV and I want name of columns what have only int64 or float and have one or more Nan value.
I know filter only columns what have int64 or float but How add condition for NaN?

```
df.loc[:, (df.dtypes == np.int64) | (df.dtypes == np.float_)].isna().any().index.values
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that `np.int64` columns can't have missing values and can't contain NaN. There are many numeric types of columns that can, foremost float64, but of course also the extension arrays.

Here's what I would do, look at all numeric columns, then get a list of all that have any NA value.

```
# get some example data
import seaborn
df = seaborn.load_dataset("penguins")
```

```
numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes("number")
column_has_nan = numeric_columns.isna().any(axis=0)
column_has_nan
```

```
bill_length_mm       True
bill_depth_mm        True
flipper_length_mm    True
body_mass_g          True
dtype: bool
```

Filter to only those where "column_has_nan" is true - the column name is in the index of that result:

```
list(column_has_nan.loc[column_has_nan].index)
```

```
# output
['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm', 'flipper_length_mm', 'body_mass_g']
```

Maybe to put it together concisely as a filter of the whole dataframe
I'd use something like this:

```
(df.select_dtypes("number")
 .loc[:, lambda df_: df_.isna().any(axis=0)])
```

Note that you can use `["float64", "int64"]` or any other selection instead of `"number"`.

Note that is is using the chained .loc with a callback - that enables using a value derived from the dataframe itself - at that point in the chain - for selection.

---

Here is a different version using `pd.Series.hasnans` which should be the most performant:

```
column_with_nan = [name for name, series in df.select_dtypes("number").items()
                   if series.hasnans]
column_with_nan
```

```
['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm', 'flipper_length_mm', 'body_mass_g']
```

Comment: I ponder if using something like: `df.select_dtypes('number').apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)` could short circuit quicker here

Comment: So yeah... while it's an apply... if there's an NA value in a column quite quickly - presumably it doesn't have to compute the rest of the array to determine there's not... I haven't tested it... but something like doing a timeit on something like: `df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index).pipe(df.columns.symmetric_difference)` but be worth a go... *shrugs* (just a random idea in the just gone past midnight kind of thoughts...)

Comment: That would be an interesting problem to solve - how to do that more lazily - but I don't see how that particular method helps (am I missing something?) - it checks for any non-NA, and we want to check for any NA.

Comment: .hasnans on a series should be the most performant. But don't know how to insert it into the code in a very fluent manner

Comment: Ooops... my inverse logic doesn't work there does it - my bad... ignore me

Comment: Well you helped me take a second look at hasnans. In my memory it was a heuristic, but it seems to say it returns an absolute fact

Comment: or a variant of your idea of using `.hasnans`... maybe: `df.apply(getattr, args=('hasnans',))[lambda v: v].index`

Comment: too cryptic IMO, useful and easy to read alternatives exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_numeric = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float64,np.int64])

nan_cols = [i for i in df_numeric .columns if df_numeric [i].isnull().any()]
```